# CSV acts different in Excel than in Sublime/C#

Tags: c#, excel, csv, multiline

I have a .csv file from a site we're updating to a completely redesigned website. The site will be rewritten in php and we need to keep the old data.

When I open the csv in excel it shows all data how it should be, one line for each product, with the downside that it converts characters that aren't html entities to weird characters. (spécifications becomes spÃ©cifications) So the excel file isn't really usable.

[image: CSV in Excel]

However when I open it in Sublime, for some reason all data is split over multiple lines. Same story in notepad and when I read it in in C#. BUT! The é does show as an é and not as Ã©

[image: CSV in sublime]

Since I have to parse the HTML in there to a different format (Some sort of pseudo code) I need to be able to read the file in a coding language.

There are 190k lines in the file, so I'm not planning on manually reformatting the file. Something tells me it has to do with the encoding used? (Saw it somewhere on the web) but I'm not sure. Most of the "multiline csv" problems I find on the web are exactly the other way around. They give solutions for excel not reading the multilines correctly.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3):

The letter `é` is encoded as the byte sequence `0xC3 0xA9` in UTF-8. So apparently your file is UTF-8-encoded. Excel expects CSV files to be encoded in Windows-1252, usually (unless a [BOM (Byte Order Mark)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) is present).

So you need to tell Excel that it should read the file as UTF-8. To do this, use the "From text" import wizard in the "Data"/"From file" ribbon where you can specify the file's encoding before importing it.

Be careful to also choose the correct delimiter, which probably explains the second part of your problem:

Since your data contains `é`s, I suspect you're from Europe (like me) where Excel uses semicolons instead of commas to separate records, whereas in the US, commas are used (they are "comma-separated values", after all). So if you use a non-European CSV tool, you might need to tell it to use a different record delimiter. No idea how to do this in Sublime specifically.

Comment: Whenever I use sublime to check .csv's I get them on one line, that's the main issue here, not the different delimiter as I don't expect it to split it into columns. Will check the excel trick tho! Thanks

Comment: When using the import tool I can't seem to get it back to the separated colums, it has a problem with the multiline now..

Comment: @Lonefish: As I said, with the import tool, you need to make sure to choose the correct delimiter (for unknown reasons, Excel doesn't consider the semicolon by default). On the first screen of the import wizard, you can choose them (and you get a preview that lets you see if Excel is separating the records correctly).

Comment: Yes, I did that, and it splits on the semicolon, but it doesn't take the mulitiline part into account. Delimiter is not a problem in this case..

Comment: By default Excel uses system delimeter which can be set in system regional and language settings. So it can be a semicolon, or can be a '|' sign or whatever else.

Comment: @MagisterCrazy: Excel only uses the system delimiter when opening a CSV file directly (Doubleclick or File/Open), not when using the import wizard.

Comment: @Lonefish: Not sure what you mean be "taking the multiline part into account". If you mean that it fails to keep quoted strings that contain newlines within a single cell (splitting them into new rows), then you also need to specify the quoting character (`"` by default) during importing.

Comment: I did specify that.. That's the weird part. However, it works in C# now, so I'm happy. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like all is fine with the data and no problems with the encoding. Excel (ignoring the encoding problem) is just interpreting the csv file with the csv format. Loading in sublime is just reading a text file, without further respect to a format.

If you want to read the file in an C# you would have to apply the csv formatting on the input file yourself. Your csv file defines a row of columns. Each column value enclosed in ", seperating the columns in one row by ; 
The spilling in sublime over multiple lines should be an effect of having line breaks within the column data.

You could read the file in C# by something like:

1. Read a line
2. Check wether it is ending within an unclosed column data
   (opening " present, but no closing one, take care about escaped " to
   be unescaped to do not get confused!)
3. Read and append new lines
   until you really read a complete content line
4. Process the content line (= data row)
5. Proceed with the next data row.

For the UTF-8 encoding see the answer above.
Hope it helps.

Comment: With a lot of headaches I managed to do it with the help of CsvHelper in C#, thanks!